# Divide the dynamic data into two parts with 200 characters

Tags: jquery

I want to divide my dynamically coming data into 2 parts. Display only 200 characters and store 
rest of the characters in a buffer variable.

i tried this code it displaying 200 characters but i want to store rest of the characters in
a buffer variable for future use.

```
$("bio").text(function(index, text) {
    return text.substr(0, 200);
});
```

If you have any idea help me

Comment: Wrap the remaining text in a `<span>..</span>` and add `display: none` to hide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like  :

```
var storage = [];

$("bio").text(function(index, text) {
  storage.push({index:index,text:text.substr(175)})
  return text.substr(0, 175);
});
```

Comment: if the full length of the text is 500, but if write the second parameter as 99999 then how it will take?

Comment: additionally you can store the index so you can access the correct entry in storage again

Comment: if i say console.log(storage) it displays all divs data in this with ",,," as separation

Comment: if i write like above,then the console.log(storage) displaying as [object Object]

Comment: this code worked for me...but how can i get the data from storage?

Answer (score 0):

You're good at it, you alread have the text variable. Like this:

```
$("bio").text(function(index, text) {
  var someVariable = text; /* full variable text */
  /* write it inside the document somewhere if you want to save it... */
  return text.substr(0, 200); // change parameter to 200 to get only 200 chars
});
```

Comment: i dont want fulltext...i want the rest of the text after split

Answer (score 0):

Substr allows you to set starting point and lenght of the string you want to parse.
So write something like this:

```
$("bio").text(function(index, text) {
  var someVariable = text; /* full variable text */
  var first= substr(0, 200);
  var second= substr(201,someVariable.length());
/* write it inside the document somewhere if you want to save it... */
  return first; 
});
```

Don't see how you can get 200 chars with substr(0, 175) anyway.
Ps code block edited from 
Afzaal Ahmad Zeeshan's answer.

Comment: edited to change lenght to length (mistyped). What kind of error you get?

Comment: there is no problem with legth the error is "Uncaught ReferenceError: substr is not defined "